# How to fix push notification title not showing correct string in swift

Tags: swift, push-notification, firebase-notifications

i've been facing some problem with FCM push notifications showing in my app.
here is the Data that the FCM send me :

```
["roomId": 253539,
"type": ROOM_SEND_MESSAGE,
"aps": {
    alert = {
        "loc-args" = (
            "TEST STRING"
        );
        "loc-key" = "CHANNEL_MESSAGE_IMAGE";
    };
    "content-available" = 1;
    sound = default;
},"messageId": 15638864319517014,
"gcm.message_id": 1563886435277772]
```

here is the problem :
whenever i receive a notification it is supposed to show me the parameters in "loc-args" but instead it shows me the value in "loc-key"
check the image bellow
[the image for my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JYM0.jpg)
and here is the code in my appDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if SMLangUtil.loadLanguage() == "fa" {
        IGGlobal.languageFileName = "localizationsFa"
    } else {
        IGGlobal.languageFileName = "localizationsEn"
    }
    let stringPath : String! = Bundle.main.path(forResource: IGGlobal.languageFileName, ofType: "json")
    MCLocalization.load(fromJSONFile: stringPath, defaultLanguage: SMLangUtil.loadLanguage())
    MCLocalization.sharedInstance().language = SMLangUtil.loadLanguage()

    if SMLangUtil.loadLanguage() == "fa" {
        UITableView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    } else {
        UITableView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    }

    SMUserManager.clearKeychainOnFirstRun()
    SMUserManager.loadFromKeychain()
    realmConfig()
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    _ = IGDatabaseManager.shared
    _ = IGWebSocketManager.sharedManager
    _ = IGFactory.shared
    _ = IGCallEventListener.sharedManager // detect cellular call state

    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

    let tabBarItemApperance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
    tabBarItemApperance.setTitleTextAttributes(convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary([convertFromNSAttributedStringKey(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor):UIColor.red]), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    tabBarItemApperance.setTitleTextAttributes(convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary([convertFromNSAttributedStringKey(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor):UIColor.white]), for: UIControl.State.selected)

    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey:"_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")

    pushNotification(application)
    detectBackground()
    IGGlobal.checkRealmFileSize()
    return true
}
  /******************* Notificaton Start *******************/

    func pushNotification(_ application: UIApplication){
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().isAutoInitEnabled = true
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            /**
             * execute following code in "IGRecentsTableViewController" and don't execute here,
             * for avoid from show permission alert in start of app when user not registered yet
             **/
            //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            //let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound, .carPlay]
            //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions,completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        self.voipRegistration()

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        voipRegistration()
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

        print("||||||NOTIFICATION||||||||")
        print(userInfo)

        if let roomId = userInfo["roomId"] as? String {
            let unreadCount = IGRoom.updateUnreadCount(roomId: Int64(roomId)!)
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = unreadCount
        }
    }
    /******************* Notificaton End *******************/
```

Comment: Image is not attached in the question.... How're you sending the push notification?

Comment: @TheTiger 
sorry for the image ,the link is added now
and the push notifications are being send using our server-side to fcm and from there to the clients,it is ok in the android but in ios i have that problem that i mentioned

Comment: Firebase push notification's payload is different from the normal apns payload. Are your backend team following the same as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)?

Comment: @TheTiger yup they are doing it ok becoz as i said the problem only happens in iOS and in Android every thing is ok :) :\

Comment: FYI Android guys can fetch and show any key manually but iOS guys can't. iOS push title depends on the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any one facing the same or similar problem i found the answer to my question :D

becoz all notifications are being handled by the os it self all i had to do was to go deeper to find the problem 
all i had to do was to re create the localizable files and **boom** every thing goes in order :)